# Using transaction scope and querying

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, oracle, entity-framework

I'm using entity framework with oracle DB. I tried to use transaction scope (because I want the option to rollback):

```
using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
{
      .....
}
```

The problem is that when I'm trying to query inside the using statement, an exception is thrown:

`Unable to load DLL 'oramts.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The Oramts.dll file is not included as a default installation when you install the Oracle client connectivity software.
I think you have to install **Oracle Services for Microsoft Transaction Server** to use TransactionScope.