# Using TransactionScope class

Tags: winforms, oracle, transactions, transactionscope

I've a .Net based thick client winforms application deployed to the clients.
I need to use TransactionScope class [System.Transactions] in the code for handling transactions on the oracle database.
Looks like this class requires oramts.dll on the client machine.
See here:
[Using transaction scope and querying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297388/entity-framework-using-transaction-scope-and-querying)

Given this, is it a good idea to use this class in a thick client application?
Because, then all the client machines would need to have this dll and other dependancies present on their machine.
Plus, if these dlls are COM based, then  they would need to be registered in the registry too.
Is oramts.dll a COM dll?And can anyone please let me know what are its dependancies?
Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`TransactionScope` is a very elegant and errorsafe way to handle transactions in the code. It's definitely worth having to add another dll.

By the way - are you sure that the dll wouldn't be needed if you created the transactions by hand?

Comment: Thanks Anders for ur response.Well,if I use ADO.Net transaction API instead of TransactionScope, then the client machine would just require to have .Net framework installed on their machines...and no extra dll or COM component would be required as incase of TransactionScope/Oracle.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment. I played with it a bit and oramts.dll was not required when using the classic ADO.Net transactions, unlike the case with using TransactionScope.